# Can I improve the way to implement simple / trivial interfaces for a record type?

Tags: f#

Say, I have interface

```
type IAB = 
   abstract A: string
   abstract B: string

type ICD =
   abstract C: string
   abstract D: string
```

I would like to build a type that implement `IAB` and `ICD`.

So the simplest type is:

```
type MyType = 
   { A: string; B: string; C: string; D: string }

   interface IAB with
      member this.A = this.A
      member this.B = this.B
   interface ICD with
      member this.C = this.C
      member this.D = this.D
```

This code looks highly repetitive. Surely I can build a normal Class that implement those interfaces, but I felt record is a better fit here, is it not?

Is there anyway I can improve it?

Comment: Hard to answer. It depends on semantics. It these are really different interfaces then there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: You're still missing the `with` after the record definition (and before the interface implementations). F# needs adds interfaces to a record via [type extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `MyType` is slightly off. It should be:

```
type MyType = { A: string; B: string; C: string; D: string} with
  interface IAB with
    member x.A = x.A
    member x.B = x.B
  interface ICD with
    member x.C = x.C
    member x.D = x.D
```

If you only ever used the type being casted to the interface, you could get away with:

```
type MyType(A: string, B: string, C: string, D: string) =
  interface IAB with
    member x.A = A
    member x.B = B
  interface ICD with
    member x.C = C
    member x.D = D
```

Answer (score 0):

F# doesn't have an implicit syntax for interfaces like C# does.  It's kind of similar to C# in the explicit direction though:

[C# Explicit Interface Implementation (tutorial)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Also, currently in F# you can't implement the same interface more than once with different generic types in the same class / type.

There are some rough edges in this area compared to a certain higher budget more polished CLR cousin.

The "SOMTHING with" pattern gets used in a few different places F# such as the match statement.  I know that I *found* that syntax you outline a little jarring when I first came at it if that's any consolation.  However, now it feels quite natural.